# BackboneJS and HandlebarsJS #unless rendering issue

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

In my Backbone App I am rendering a View where it loads data from my database. If there is no data, I want it to display a message like "There's no data". I used the `#unless`-method but my issue is, that this message gets displayed while the data gets loaded/rendered and then it disappears when the data is ready and gets displayed. My Handlebars Template looks like this:

```
{{#each this}}
<div>
  <div>        
    <article>
        {{#if cover_image}}
        <img src="{{cover_image}}">
        {{else}}
        <img src="noimage.jpg" />
        {{/if}}
    </article> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>{{album_title}}</h2>
    <h4>
        {{#if physicalReleaseDate}}
        <time datetime="2014-01-10">({{physicalReleaseDate}})</time>
        {{else}}
        <time datetime="2014-01-10">({{digitalReleaseDate}})</time>
        {{/if}}                 
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
        <ol>
            {{#each tracks}}
            <li>{{track_title}}<span>{{track_duration}}</span></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}

{{#unless this}}
<div class="noAlbums">
    <h2>There's no data</h2>
</div>
{{/unless}}
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need an [inverted section](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#inverted-sections)

Example from docs:

Model:

```
    {
      "repos": []
    }
```

Template:

```
    {{#repos}}<b>{{name}}</b>{{/repos}}
    {{^repos}}No repos :({{/repos}}
```